# Can I set the width of AixsY?

Tags: lightningchart

LightningChart Version: 4.0.2.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh7da.png)

Can I align the two charts by setting the y-axis width to a constant value? Is there any other property or method to achieve this effect?

I tried to use addAxisY() to add YAxis to the second chart ,then use setVisible(false) to make it invisible. But the length of the negative number or the value will make the width of them inconsistent.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DGQe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Axis.setThickness` should be exactly what you are looking for

https://lightningchart.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v4.0.2/classes/Axis.html#setThickness